# Command prompt convert png to swf

Tags: command-line, flash, png, jpeg, server-side

I want to let a user upload a PNG-file with alpha transparency and have it compiled by the server to a swf-file with jpeg compression on the embedded PNG-file.

How can I make this happen?

I thought first I'd just construct a class and compile it with Flex Framework, but Flex does not compress the embedded PNG-files. You who have tried have probably ended up making an assets.swf file compiled from within the Flash IDE.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Kind regards,
nitech

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [swftools](http://www.swftools.org) package there is a command [png2swf](http://www.swftools.org/png2swf.html). Use the -j switch for jpeg compression.

Comment: Superb :-) Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), I recall seeing it used by a lot of shared-hosting web-servers. It can be executed on the command line or in scripts.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know ImageMagick handles swf files! This works but it doesn't compress the image to JPG. I guess an extra step would easily resolve that.

Comment: hey I don't know what it does, i just recall seeing it on a server! ;D